# Typo3 6.0.2 Add RTE Class

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rte

how can i add new classes to TYPO3 RTE (version 6.0.2)
i tried the same way as with Typo3 4 :
- created a css file in fileadmin folder (fileadmin/css/rte.css)
- add style in this css file
- add those lines in page TSConfig :

```
RTE.default {
classesParagraph >
classesTable >
classesTD >
classesLinks >
classesCharacter >
classesAnchor >
classesImage >

ignoreMainStyleOverride=1
showTagFreeClasses=1

contentCSS = /fileadmin/css/rte.css

showButtons = *

showTagFreeClasses = 1

proc.allowedClasses >
}

RTE.classes {
left.name=Float left
}
```

but nothing change, my added classes won't show in RTE...

thanks in advance.

Comment: **You can see here for TYPO3 Version 7.6.X**,
[Add classes in RTE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050092/cannot-choose-text-style-in-rte/38370419#38370419)

Answer (score 4):

I think some configuration options have changed in newer versions of TYPO3.

**Deprecated property => Use instead**

- disableRightClick => contextMenu.disable
- disableContextMenu => contextMenu.disable
- hidePStyleItems => buttons.formatblock.removeItems
- hideFontFaces => buttons.fontstyle.removeItems
- fontFace => buttons.fontstyle.addItems
- hideFontSizes => buttons.fontsize.removeItems
- fontSize => buttons.fontsize.addItems
- classesCharacter => buttons.textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses
- classesParagraph => buttons.blockstyle.tags.div.allowedClasses
- classesTable => buttons.blockstyle.tags.table.allowedClasses
- classesTD => buttons.blockstyle.tags.td.allowedClasses
- classesImage => buttons.image.properties.class.allowedClasses
- classesLinks => buttons.link.properties.class.allowedClasses
- blindImageOptions => buttons.image.options.removeItems
- blindLinkOptions => buttons.link.options.removeItems
- defaultLinkTarget => buttons.link.properties.target.default
- RTE.default.classesAnchor => RTE.default.buttons.link.properties.class.allowedClasses
- RTE.default.classesAnchor.default.[link-type] => RTE.default.buttons.link.[link-type].properties.class.default
- mainStyleOverride => contentCSS
- mainStyleOverride_add.[key] => contentCSS
- mainStyle_font => contentCSS
- mainStyle_size => contentCSS
- mainStyle_color => contentCSS
- mainStyle_bgcolor => contentCSS
- inlineStyle.[any-keystring] => contentCSS
- ignoreMainStyleOverride => n.a.
- disableTYPO3Browsers => buttons.image.TYPO3Browser.disabled and buttons.link.TYPO3Browser.disabled
- showTagFreeClasses => buttons.blockstyle.showTagFreeClasses and buttons.textstyle.showTagFreeClasses
- disablePCexamples => buttons.blockstyle.disableStyleOnOptionLabel and buttons.textstyle.disableStyleOnOptionLabel

See here: http://forge.typo3.org/issues/28325

Answer (score 2):

In case you still need help: Here is another question with a helpful answer:
[Cannot choose text style in RTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050092/cannot-choose-text-style-in-rte)

I had the same problem with TYPO3 6.0.2 and many tutorials or forum entries I found contained deprecated properties. With the answer to the aforemetnioned question it worked.

Answer (score 0):

css file rte.css

```
a.youtube-vintage, a.fb-vintage, a.www-vintage {
    color: #9A3811;
}
```

pagets config

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //    RTE
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
    RTE.classes{
      youtube-vintage{
          name = youtube
          value = color:#636466; font-size:15px;
      } 
      fb-vintage{
          name = fb
          value = color:#9A3811;
      }
      www-vintage{
          name = www
          value = color:#9A3811;

      }
    }

    RTE.default{
      ignoreMainStyleOverride = 1 
      useCSS = 1
      showTagFreeClasses = 1
      contentCSS = fileadmin/templates/css/rte.css
      buttons {
        blockstyle.tags.div.allowedClasses := addToList(youtube-vintage, fb-vintage, www-vintage)
        blockstyle.tags.p.allowedClasses := addToList(youtube-vintage, fb-vintage, www-vintage)
        textstyle.tags.span.allowedClasses := addToList(youtube-vintage, fb-vintage, www-vintage)
      }
      proc.allowedClasses := addToList(youtube-vintage, fb-vintage, www-vintage)
    }
```

Comment: For TYPO3 7.6.X, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050092/cannot-choose-text-style-in-rte/38370419#38370419